# Removing the word "Chapter" from ToC using titlesec/titletoc

Tags: titlesec

The goal is to simulate the style of [this](http://groups.di.unipi.it/%7Eottavian/files/phd_thesis.pdf) document. I managed to get rid of the "Chapter" word in chapter names using `titlesec`.
And then I tried to do the same for the ToC, using e.g.

```
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[0pt]                                               % left margin
{}%
{\contentsmargin{0pt}                               % numbered entry format
    \thecontentslabel\enspace%
    \large\scshape}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\large}                        % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}                 % filler-page format (e.g dots)
[]                                                  % below code (e.g vertical space)
```

This changes the name of the chapter fine, but the "Chapter X"-type of prefix is still there.
How to get rid of it?
[image]

I would like to achieve this:
[image]

What could be done?

EDIT: The template is [here](https://projects.cs.dal.ca/dalthesis/), and my MWE file is [here](https://pastebin.com/qptUFNEs)

Comment: That's the default behaviour, so we should have a short, yet complete code, with document class, relevant packages and your own related macros to understand  why it is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can patch the document class macro that writes to the `.toc` file.

```latex
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\dal@chapter}
 {\numberline{\@chapapp\space\thechapter}}
 {\numberline{\thechapter}}
 {}{}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to add `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}` before the `titlecontents` in the above example, and we get rid of the "Chapter" word in the table of contents.